# Asp Net Core Multiple Authentication Cookies with Claims-Base Authorization

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, authorization

I'm use asp.net core and I'm going to have multiple cookies that I use for authorization per use. Each cookie would contain general authorization information plus information to create claims.

So the question is if I have two cookies that look like this:

Cookie 1

- Claim A
- Claim B

Cookie 2

- Claim A
- Claim C

If I had an authorization filter that required that a user had Clam C, would the use get access, or would get they get rejected because both cookies don't have Claim C?

Comment: maybe misprint, but why you say "both cookies don't have Claim C" as Cookie 2 has it?

Comment: I'm asking if it's mandatory that both cookies have Claim C or if the user will be authorized because one of the cookies has Claim C